# Bashshell - argument too long message shows after for loop-echo command

Tags: bash, file, for-loop, echo, command-line-arguments

I am working on CentOS with bash shell.

I do not see anything wrong in the code, but it keeps print `arguments list too long` error.

It is not only apply to `aws cp`, after for `cat /dev/null > $FILE_DIR/dailey_member.csv` also prints same message.

```
echo " ===== dailey vote by member"
cat /dev/null > $FILE_DIR/dailey_member.csv
QUERY_DAILEY_MEMBER_RS=`mysql -h $MYSQL_URL -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PW $MYSQL_SCHEMA -e "SELECT voteDate, usrId, count(usrId) FROM tbl_vote GROUP BY voteDate, usrId;"`
IFS=$'\n' LINES=($QUERY_DAILEY_MEMBER_RS)
for i in "${!LINES[@]}"; do
    LINE_IDX=$i
    LINE=${LINES[$LINE_IDX]}
    LINE=${LINE//$'\t'/,}
    echo -e $LINE >> $FILE_DIR/dailey_member.csv
done
echo "aws s3 cp $FILE_DIR/dailey_member.csv " $S3_PATH # copy output works.
aws s3 cp "$FILE_DIR/dailey_member.csv" $S3_PATH
exit 0
```

How could I fix this?

Thanks.

FYI, 
What I am trying to do is...

- do MYSQL query
- parse result and write as csv file
- send to s3 repository, so people can download file

============== edited #1 ================

I set my variable like on top of the file ...

```
export FILE_DIR="/home/jyoh/applications18/cron/file"
export S3_PATH="s3://juneyoung/applications18/voteLogs/"
```

The result puts on the console.

```
[jyoh@ip-XX-XX-X-XXX cron]$ sh ./daileyVoteByMember.sh 
 ===== dailey vote by member
aws s3 cp /home/jyoh/applications18/cron/file/dailey_member.csv s3://juneyoung/applications18/voteLogs/
./daileyVoteByMember.sh: line 27: /usr/bin/aws: arguments list too long
[jyoh@ip-XX-XX-X-XXX cron]$ aws s3 cp /home/jyoh/applications18/cron/file/dailey_member.csv s3://juneyoung/applications18/voteLogs/
upload: file/dailey_member.csv to s3://juneyoung/applications18/voteLogs/dailey_member.csv
```

line27 is where `aws s3 cp "$FILE_DIR/dailey_member.csv" $S3_PATH` is.

============== edited #2 ================

result with option `-x`.

```
...SKIP...

+ LINE_IDX=265782
+ LINE='20180129    9>2387463256785462364   1'
+ LINE='20180129,9>2387463256785462364,1'
+ echo -e '20180129,9>2387463256785462364,1'
+ for i in '"${!LINES[@]}"'
+ LINE_IDX=265783
+ LINE='20180129    9>3658743656387567834   1'
+ LINE='20180129,9>3658743656387567834,1'
+ echo -e '20180129,9>3658743656387567834,1'
+ echo 'aws s3 cp /home/jyoh/applications18/cron/file/dailey_member.csv s3://juneyoung/applications18/voteLogs/'
+ aws s3 cp /home/jyoh/applications18/cron/file/dailey_member.csv s3://juneyoung/applications18/voteLogs/
./daileyVoteByMember.sh: line 27: /usr/bin/aws: arguments list too long
+ exit 0
```

============== edited #3 ================

Copy `aws` in new bash file and execute

the file contents

```
#! /bin/bash

aws s3 cp /home/jyoh/applications18/cron/file/dailey_member.csv s3://juneyoung/applications18/voteLogs/

exit 0
```

console output

```
[jyoh@ip-XX-XX-X-XXX cron]$ sh testSh.sh 
upload: file/dailey_member.csv to s3://juneyoung/applications18/voteLogs/
```

============== edited #4 ================

This works fine and clean. Maybe some problem with `for` and `>>` file redirection?

```
function sendS3 () {
   echo "S3 send command : aws s3 cp $1 $S3_PATH"     
   aws s3 cp $1 $S3_PATH
}

echo " ===== daily vote"
mysql -h "$MYSQL_URL" -u"$MYSQL_USER" -p"$MYSQL_PW" "$MYSQL_SCHEMA" -e "SELECT QUERY #1;" | sed $'s/\t/,/g' > "$FILE_DIR"/daily.csv
sendS3 "$FILE_DIR"/daily.csv


echo " ===== dailey vote by member"
mysql -h "$MYSQL_URL" -u"$MYSQL_USER" -p"$MYSQL_PW" "$MYSQL_SCHEMA" -e "SELECT QUERY #2;" | sed $'s/\t/,/g' > "$FILE_DIR"/daily_member.csv
sendS3 "$FILE_DIR"/dailey_member.csv


echo " ===== daily vote by ip"
mysql -h "$MYSQL_URL" -u"$MYSQL_USER" -p"$MYSQL_PW" "$MYSQL_SCHEMA" -e "SELECT QUERY #3" | sed $'s/\t/,/g' > "$FILE_DIR"/daily_ip.csv
sendS3 "$FILE_DIR"/daily_ip.csv


echo " ===== daily vote by member,item"
mysql -h "$MYSQL_URL" -u"$MYSQL_USER" -p"$MYSQL_PW" "$MYSQL_SCHEMA" -e "SELECT QUERY #4" | sed $'s/\t/,/g' > "$FILE_DIR"/daily_item.csv
sendS3 "$FILE_DIR"/daily_item.csv

exit 0
```

============== edited #5 ================

This is the full script. I replaced url and some variables for security.

```
#! /bin/bash

export SLACK_URL="SLACK_API_URL"
export MYSQL_URL="MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL"
export MYSQL_USER="MYSQL_USER"
export MYSQL_PW="MYSQL_PW"
export MYSQL_SCHEMA="USER"

export FILE_DIR="FILE_PATH"

export QUERY_DAILY_RS=""
export QUERY_DAILY_MEMBER_RS=""
export QUERY_DAILY_IP_RS=""
export QUERY_DAILY_MEMBER_ITEM_RS=""
export S3_PATH="S3_URL_TO_STORE"

echo -e "Sending vote report to Slack"
echo $MYSQL_URL
echo $MYSQL_USER::$MYSQL_PW


function sendS3 () {
   echo "S3 send command : aws s3 cp $1 $S3_PATH"     
   aws s3 cp $1 $S3_PATH
}


echo " ===== daily vote"
cat /dev/null > $FILE_DIR/daily.csv
QUERY_DAILY_RS=`mysql SELECT QUERY 1;`
IFS=$'\n' LINES=($QUERY_DAILY_RS)
for i in "${!LINES[@]}"; do
    LINE_IDX=$i
    LINE=${LINES[$LINE_IDX]}
    LINE=${LINE//$'\t'/,}
    echo -e $LINE >> "$FILE_DIR"/daily.csv
done
sendS3 "$FILE_DIR/daily.csv"



echo " ===== daily vote by member"
cat /dev/null > $FILE_DIR/daily_member.csv
QUERY_DAILY_MEMBER_RS=`mysql SELECT QUERY 2`
IFS=$'\n' LINES=($QUERY_DAILY_MEMBER_RS)
for i in "${!LINES[@]}"; do
    LINE_IDX=$i
    LINE=${LINES[$LINE_IDX]}
    LINE=${LINE//$'\t'/,}
    echo -e $LINE >> $FILE_DIR/daily_member.csv
done
sendS3 "$FILE_DIR/daily_member.csv"



echo " ===== daily vote by ip"
cat /dev/null > $FILE_DIR/daily_ip.csv
QUERY_DAILY_IP_RS=`mysql SELECT QUERY 3`
IFS=$'\n' LINES=($QUERY_DAILY_IP_RS)
for i in "${!LINES[@]}"; do
    LINE_IDX=$i
    LINE=${LINES[$LINE_IDX]}
    LINE=${LINE//$'\t'/,}
    echo -e $LINE >> $FILE_DIR/daily_ip.csv
done
sendS3 "$FILE_DIR/daily_ip.csv"



echo " ===== daily vote by member,item"
cat /dev/null > $FILE_DIR/daily_member_item.csv
QUERY_DAILY_MEMBER_ITEM_RS=`mysql SELECT QUERY 4`
IFS=$'\n' LINES=($QUERY_DAILY_MEMBER_ITEM_RS)
for i in "${!LINES[@]}"; do
    LINE_IDX=$i
    LINE=${LINES[$LINE_IDX]}
    LINE=${LINE//$'\t'/,}
    echo -e $LINE >> $FILE_DIR/daily_member_item.csv
done

sendS3 "$FILE_DIR/daily_member_item.csv"
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Vote data collecting done"}' $SLACK_URL

exit 0
```

Comment: is there any space characters in your $FILE_DIR? try : cat /dev/null > "$FILE_DIR"/dailey_member.csv

Comment: @yudongshen Thanks for the answer, but I already tried that one.

Comment: Are you sure the command `cat /dev/null > "$FILE_DIR"/dailey_member.csv` really prints `arguments list too long` and not other script lines?. Please run your script in 
"**debugging mode**" (`sh -x`). Please, show us also the value of the `FILE_DIR` variable.

Comment: Show the values of the variables you have, $FILE_DIR and $S3_PATH at least, there might be something in there...

echo it first...

Comment: @MontyMontemayor Add file declaration and echo and execution result. Copy echo result and execute is works, but it does not in bash

Comment: I translated `arguments list too long` since os language is Korean.

Comment: it seems it is coming from inside aws command and not from your main script.

Comment: @Jdamian add result with `-x` option.

Comment: @MontyMontemayor But I still do not get it, since the command works independently with copy and paste.

Comment: which command? the line aws .. ?
put it inside a new script with just that line. use shebang and let us now the output.

Comment: I guess you have misspelled "daily" throughout.

Comment: and call "getconf ARG_MAX" from inside that script, show us the output of this as well

Comment: Tangentially, capturing the result as a string so you can copy it to an array (unquoted!) so you can loop over it is potentially a huge waste of memory. Just pipe `mysql` output into a `while IFS=$'\n' read -r line` loop if you have no other reason to keep the results in memory.

Comment: Looking at this in more detail, this looks like you simply need `mysql | sed $'s/\t/,/g' > file.csv` though there is probably some option to have MySQL create output in the format you need directly.

Comment: But those are tangential remarks I agree with @MontyMontemayor that this seems to be a bug in `aws s3 cp`

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for pointing.

Comment: `echo -e $LINE` without quotes looks like a bug waiting to blow up on you anyway. [You need quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) unless you specifically *require* the shell to perform whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion on the value.

Comment: @MontyMontemayor in new file result of `getconf ARG_MAX` is `2621440`, but In the original script it returns `arguments list too long`

Comment: @tripleee It works beautiful you suggested in reply. using `mysql` and `sed`, a wonderful method to achieve the goal I mentioned. b

Comment: As @MontyMontemayor pointed out, this issue has to do with `aws`, not with `bash`. And in the debug mode, `cat /dev/null > "$FILE_DIR"/dailey_member.csv` shows no error message.

Comment: Did aws command ran without any issues in the new script?  If it did, there's something more in the original script that is limiting the ARG_MAX causing this issue.

Comment: @Jdamian Indeed `cat` does not the problem - I just can not reproduce. In original script, I got same logic of this code four times and after `for` ~ `done`, this error happens.

Comment: @MontyMontemayor I added extra information to the post. I am not sure what is different with `aws` command...

Comment: Using `sh` to run a `bash` script is also at the very least misdirected. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash (and read the question about quoting I linked to again; you are still making the same type of mistake with complete abandon).

Comment: btw, your shebang has space after !, there should be no space.  
`#! /bin/bash`  

so... aws ran without any issues in a separate script, but not in the original one. I highly suspect that it is somewhere in your original script that is causing it, based from what you are telling us now, this doesn't seem an aws issue, even a simple command i.e getconf would produce the same error. I suggest to carefully review your original script. But without your letting us look at your entire script, there's no way we can assist you further, we can only guess.

Comment: @MontyMontemayor Thanks. I thought using like `#! /bin/bash` is normal. I added the original script to the post. please review the script, tell me anything not good.

Comment: BTW, environment variables count against your maximum command-line length (so if you `export` excessively large variables, then you can prevent even external programs with short command lines from running). If any scripts you've run go will-nilly `export`ing things that could just as easily be shell-local variables instead of exporting them to the environment, that's liable to be an exacerbating factor. Check the length of values you've `export`ed, and if you don't need to `export` something, then **don't**.

Comment: If you haven't run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixed what it identifies, by the way, I'd suggest doing that sooner rather than later.

Comment: as what @CharlesDuffy suggested, ran it through shellcheck, and fix your shebang. Run it and see if the error still exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your code is setting too many (or too-large) environment variables.**

Environment variables live in the same per-process space as command line arguments, so exporting variables to the environment reduces the space available for command-line arguments. (If you aren't explicitly `export`ing content inside your loop, check whether `echo $-` inside your script contains `a`, a flag which tells the shell to automatically export every variable set; if it does, find the place where you're turning that option on, and disable it).

To demonstrate this (with GNU `xargs`), you can run:

```
xargs --show-limits </dev/null
```

Output *should* look something like:

```
Your environment variables take up 2615 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 257481
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 254866
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072
Maximum parallelism (--max-procs must be no greater): 2147483647
```

Subtract the number on the second line from the number on the first line, and that's your maximum command-line length (roughly). Number on the first line too big? Look through your environment, and either `unset` large variables, or don't `export` them in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for all. using `export` is the one of my habits when I writing a script. (`#! /bin/bash` also... I removed the empty space) I should care of using `export` keyword. bb