# Add to existing json file using jq

Tags: json, bash, loops, jq, artifactory-query-lang

I have an [Artifactory AQL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language) Spec file in JSON format. The spec file is as follows:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "aql": {
        "items.find": {
          "repo": "release-repo",
          "modified": { "$before": "30d" },
          "type": { "$eq": "folder" },
          "depth": "2"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

let's say I run a gitlab api query to acquire a list of SHAs that I want to iterate through and add to this json spec file.. The list of SHAs are assigned to a variable..

```
"a991fef6bb9e9759d513fd4b277fe3674b44e4f4"
"5a562d34bb1d4ab4264acc2c61327651218524ad"
"d4e296c35644743e58aed35d1afb87e34d6c8823"
```

I would like to iterate through all these commit IDs in and add them one by one to the json so that they are in this format:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "aql": {
        "items.find": {
          "repo": "release-repo",
          "modified": { "$before": "30d" },
          "type": { "$eq": "folder" },
          "$or": [
            {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "name": {
                    "$nmatch": "*a991fef6bb9e9759d513fd4b277fe3674b44e4f4*"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "name": {
                    "$nmatch": "*5a562d34bb1d4ab4264acc2c61327651218524ad*"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "name": {
                    "$nmatch": "*d4e296c35644743e58aed35d1afb87e34d6c8823*"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "depth": "2"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The list of SHAs returned from the gitlab api query will be different everything and that's why I'd like this to be a dynamic entry or update every time. The number of returned SHAs will also be different... Could return 10 one day or it could return 50 on another day.

Comment: You have quotes in your shell variable? (What *exactly* is its format?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the variable as follows:

export result=$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: *************" 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/265/repository/tags?per_page=800&order_by=updated&sort=desc'
| jq '.[] | select (.name | contains ("release")) | .commit.id')

Which returns:

echo $results

"a991fef6bb9e9759d513fd4b277fe3674b44e4f4" "5a562d34bb1d4ab4264acc2c61327651218524ad" "d4e296c35644743e58aed35d1afb87e34d6c8823"

Comment: (I'm actually in the middle of an answer that assumes that it's a shell array, and that the quotes are syntactic rather than literal).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I can update the command to remove the quotes from the list of SHAs

Comment: `echo $results` is much less useful than you'd think (its output is ambiguous in a surprising number of ways). Use `declare -p results` instead.

Comment: ([BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) starts to touch on the faults of unquoted `echo`s... though even quoted, there's a lot of ambiguity; see the APPLICATION USAGE section of the [POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html)).

Comment: BTW, I don't recommend `export`ing variables unless you have a specific and compelling reason to do so. Exporting a shell variable into the environment means it's stored in the same region of memory also used for command-line arguments, so you're making your maximum allowed command-line length shorter. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48486201/bashshell-argument-too-long-message-shows-after-for-loop-echo-command/48523766#48523766

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

template='{
  "files": [
    {
      "aql": {
        "items.find": {
          "repo": "release-repo",
          "modified": { "$before": "30d" },
          "type": { "$eq": "folder" },
          "$or": [],
          "depth": "2"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}'

shas=(
  "a991fef6bb9e9759d513fd4b277fe3674b44e4f4"
  "5a562d34bb1d4ab4264acc2c61327651218524ad"
  "d4e296c35644743e58aed35d1afb87e34d6c8823"
)

jq -n \
        --argjson template "$template" \
        --arg shas_str "${shas[*]}" \
'
reduce ($shas_str | split(" ") | .[]) as $sha ($template;
  .files[0].aql["items.find"]["$or"] += [{
    "$and": [{"name": {"$nmatch": ("*" + $sha + "*")}}]
  }]
)
'
```

...emits as output:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "aql": {
        "items.find": {
          "repo": "release-repo",
          "modified": {
            "$before": "30d"
          },
          "type": {
            "$eq": "folder"
          },
          "$or": [
            {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "name": {
                    "$nmatch": "*a991fef6bb9e9759d513fd4b277fe3674b44e4f4*"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "name": {
                    "$nmatch": "*5a562d34bb1d4ab4264acc2c61327651218524ad*"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "name": {
                    "$nmatch": "*d4e296c35644743e58aed35d1afb87e34d6c8823*"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "depth": "2"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reduce-free solution. It makes some inessential assumptions -
 that the sha strings are presented as a stream of strings on STDIN, and that the Artifactory spec is in a file named spec.json.  Here is the jq program:

```
map( {"$and": [ {name: { "$nmatch": "*\(.)*" }}]} ) as $x
| $spec[0] | (.files[0].aql."items.find"."$or" = $x)
```

The jq invocation might look like this:

```
jq -s --slurpfile spec spec.json -f program.jq <<< "${shas[*]}"
```